# Windows Phone apps not working through proxy server

Tags: wifi

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 and my college Wi-Fi uses proxy servers to connect. Apps like WhatsApp, Hike, Skype, etc. don't work through proxy servers. Can any of you help?

Comment: Talk to your college's IT department?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as on Windows, WP apps can open direct connections and therefore bypass proxies. While most apps will only need to use HTTP traffic (for web browsing or web services) and can therefore use the built-in HTTP client functions (which will respect the phone's proxy setting), apps that open direct TCP or UDP sockets are not subject to the system proxy settings.

Some such apps implement their own support for proxies. For example, Cisco WebEx added proxy support at some point. However, it is not universal. Interestingly, Skype on the desktop does support proxies, either by getting the system proxy settings (which I don't think is possible for a WP app, though I may be mistaken) or by letting the user set them manually.

Comment: so you say its not possible to have them under work??

Comment: You either need to bypass the proxy (get the college IT to allow this, or use another connection such as your cellular data), get the apps themselves to support it (some of them might - check their Settings pages - but in general if they don't then the developers will need to update them with proxy support as a new feature), or run your data through an invisible proxy that in turn runs it all through the "real" proxy, basically a gateway that funnels all its traffic to a proxy. You could probably set up a PC as such a gateway, but it would only work near the PC then.